# how to list all the controllers used when running a ros package

Tags: ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

im trying to find all the controllers that this https://github.com/TEAMIFOR/ifor_offb2 package is using (on iris quadrotor, from px4 firmware)

i tried
rosrun controller_manager controller_manager list
but it doesn't show anything

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251998/how-to-list-all-the-controllers-used-when-running-a-ros-package/) by [serf](https://answers.ros.org/users/28944/serf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no experience with the package you link to, but from a cursory glance at the code, I don't think it uses `ros_control` or exposes any of the infrastructure the `controller_manager` would use to list controllers.

Are you sure that this is supposed to work that way? Have you asked the authors?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [serf](https://answers.ros.org/users/28944/serf/) on 2017-01-15**:
hmm i thought so, so how do i go about writing something similar using controllers, there are barely any tutorials so could you give me a small insight as to how i should go about writing this?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-15**:
I have no experience with UAVs, so I'm afraid I wouldn't be the best person to assist you.

**Comment by [serf](https://answers.ros.org/users/28944/serf/) on 2017-01-15**:
oh anyway thanks alot for your help